# Is there a bug in the flags page?

Tags: support, 10k-tools

[image]

It doesn't seem like I can click anywhere or do anything... Help?

Comment: the bits must have missed on the way through wire! same result on hard refreshing the page? Did you try logging in again? Link to the problem to check if it is global

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is intentional. Nor can I.

You should click through the question, and read it for context before deciding what you want to do from the question.

At least that's how it works for now.

---

For reference the question link is the one just below the full horizontal line. The shorter one breaks the question title from the comment text.